# SP Workflow keep sending email when InfoPath form is modified

Tags: sharepoint-server, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-email, email-notification

I have a simple workflow created to basically send a email when the send a notification button is clicked on the form. I have a separate button to be able to save the form once it's been updated but, ever time the form is saved it sends out an email. I just want one email to be sent.

The workflow is if the value is send an email to the people entered the people picker field. Log to workflow list sent email. Go to end workflow.

What do I need to do to stop the workflow after that first email. I used sharepoint designer 2013 also SP workflow 2013. Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you workflow trigger is set as "`When the item is modified`". If you only want the email to be sent on the first time. You can change the trigger to be "`When the item is created`". So Email will be sent only when you save the form first time and create a new list item.